# Nesting methods in coffee script

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am currently trying to make something in coffee script that requires nesting methods. I want something like this.

```
class test
    constructor: (one, two, three) ->
        #do something with one two and three
    @method1: (one, two) ->
         #do something with vars
         @method2: (one, two, three, four) ->
            #do something with vars
            @method3:() ->
                    #do something
```

I want to be able to run the methods like this.

```
main = new test(one, two, three)
meth1 = main.method1(four, five)
meth2 = meth1.method2(six, seven, eight, nine)
meth3 = meth2.method3()
```

I also want to be able to return values, for example.

```
variable = new test(one, two, three).method1(four, five).something
```

The one thing that i don't want is for the different methods to all be accessible from the one place, for example, i don't want this to happen:

```
new test(one, two, three).method3()
```

I don't know if this will help, but the actions I want to preform only interact with the HTML on the page.

I have been trying various methods of doing this for a while, but so far nothing has worked completely.

Answer (score 1):

This is not called *nesting*, but [*chaining*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining). To enable that, you will have to return `test` instances from the chainable methods. That can be the input instance (which you mutated) or a new instance which copies some properties from the input and changes others (not mutating the input).

Have a look at [these questions/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method-chaining+javascript) for practical examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to chain your methods, you can return `this` as a return value for each of them. However, if you only want some methods to be accessible in a specific order, you can return an `object` that only implements the desired interface instead of returning `this`.

In the example below, only `method1` is accessible on the `Test` instance, but the result of calling `method1` is an `object` that has a `method2` function. Also, every returned objects have a `getResult` function that allows you to retrieve the result of the chained functions and resets `@result` to the initial result.

There are other ways of preserving function call states like using [`curried`](http://ejohn.org/blog/partial-functions-in-javascript/) functions.

```
class Test
    constructor: (one, two, three) ->
        @initialResult = @result = one + two + three
        @getResult = =>
            result = @result
            @result = @initialResult
            result
    method1: (four, five) ->
        @result += four + five

        getResult: @getResult
        method2: (six, seven, eigth, nine) =>
            @result += six + seven + eigth + nine
            getResult: @getResult


t = new Test(1, 2, 3)

console.log(t.getResult())

console.log(t.method1(4, 5).method2(6, 7 ,8, 9).getResult())

console.log(t.method1(1, 2).getResult())

console.log(typeof t.method2) #undefined
```

Comment: I think the function parameters should not be prefixed with `@`

Comment: @Bergi, I updated the example for something that makes more sense ;)

Answer (score 0):

While method chaining has been covered already, I think what you're trying to do could be accomplished by currying / partial application. If you're writing something a little more functional, you'd essentially want `meth1` to take some arguments and return `meth2`, which would take more arguments and return `meth3`, which would do something using all the arguments that were passed in right from `meth1`.

Here's a couple of blog posts that talk about currying / partial application.

http://ejohn.org/blog/partial-functions-in-javascript/

http://www.drdobbs.com/open-source/currying-and-partial-functions-in-javasc/231001821

Comment: You mean `((one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine) -> …).curry()`? Btw, neither of the two sites you linked to got currying/schönfinkelizing right.

Comment: No, I mean `meth1(one, two, three)(four, five, six)(seven, eight, nine)`. And they're the only reputable ones I could find for JS/Coffee. I've tried explaining it with Python here: http://hangar.runway7.net/python/partial-functions-currying

Comment: No, neither `partial` nor `bind` do currying. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Contrast_with_partial_function_application

Comment: I'm looking at the definition right now and it looks like `partial` (at least in Python) is exactly what does that... what am I missing?

Comment: No. When you do `p = f.partial(x,y)`, then `p(z)` is equivalent to `f(x,y,z)`. If you did `c = f.curry()`, then the equivalent would be `c(x)(y)(z)`.